# How can I make different columns using only one column in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
   Name        Facilities                  Start_Date      End_Date
0  Sai      PoolFree parkingSpa            22-02-2021     23/02/2021
1  Surya    PoolSpaGymRestaurantBatch hub  15-01-2021     19/02/2021
2  Sandya   Free parkingSpaKitchen         15-01-2021     22/01/2021
3  Shyam    PoolFree parkingKitchen        29-01-2021     02/02/2021
```

Now I want to change this data frame like below:

```
   Name        Pool   Free parking   Spa   Gym  Restaurant  Bath hub   Start_Date   End_Date            
0  Sai         yes      yes          yes  no     no         no         22-02-2021   23-02-2021  
1  Surya       yes      no           yes  yes    yes        yes        15-01-2021   19-02-2021
2  Sandya      no       yes          yes  no     no         no         15-01-2021   22-01-2021
3  Shyam       yes      yes          yes  no     no         no         29-01-2021   02-02-2021
```

This is my required output, weather it has facility gives as yes otherwise gives as no and also change the End_Date column as shown. For this how to write a code, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the method `.contains` to the column `Facilities` and combine that with your preferred `case`-like function.

For example, imagine your data is stored in `df`. Then:

```py
import numpy as np
df['Spa'] = np.where(df['Facilities'].str.contains('Spa'), 'Yes', 'No')
```

In doing so, you may have noticed that `df['Facilities'].str.contains('Spa')` returns a boolean column. Hence, you can skip the `np.where()` and directly assign:

```py
df['Spa'] = df['Facilities'].str.contains('Spa')
```

In this case, `True` means `'Yes'` and `False` means `'No'`.

If you want to do this all in a single loop:

```
for facility in ['Pool','Spa','Free parking','Gym','Restaurant','Bathtub']:
    df[facility] = df['Facilities'].str.contains(facility)
```

As for replacing the `/` character with `-` in `End_Date`:

```py
df['End_Date'] = df['End_Date'].str.replace('/', '-')
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the End_Date column. In the End_Date column I want to change this symbol '/' to this symbol '-'

Comment: Hi @SaiKumar . I updated the answer. Let me know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.facilities.str.contains` to find each facility and create a column for it.

```
     name                     facilities
0     Sai            PoolFree parkingSpa
1   Surya  PoolSpaGymRestaurantBatch hub
2  Sandya         Free parkingSpaKitchen
3   Shyam        PoolFree parkingKitchen
```

```py
facilities = ['Pool','Free parking','Spa']
for i in facilities:
     df.loc[df.facilities.str.contains(i),i] = 'yes'

df = df.fillna('no').drop(columns=['facilities'])
```

```
     name Pool Free parking  Spa
0     Sai  yes          yes  yes
1   Surya  yes           no  yes
2  Sandya   no          yes  yes
3   Shyam  yes          yes   no
```